# PHP Function MySQL Save

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make some functions to save easily my send-data.
This why I'm trying to build it with functions but when I send information to the function I get errors:

> Undefined variable: db in .... on line 53
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in .... on
>   line 53

My Question is, is it possible to save in a function a mysql statement?

PHP Code:

```
require_once("../connection.php");

function saveNews($k_id, $k_news)
{
    $query_s_news   =   $db->prepare("UPDATE `benachrichtigung` SET `Newsletter` = :news WHERE `KundeID` = :id"); // This is the Errorline
    $query_s_news->execute(array(
        'news'      =>  $k_news,
        'id'        =>  $k_id
    ));
}        

if(isset($_POST["s_prod"]))
{
    $s_news         =   filter_var($_POST["s_news"],                                                              
    FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if($s_news)
    {
         if($s_news == 1)
         {
             saveNews($_SESSION["id"], 0); 
         }
         else if($s_news == 2)
         {
             saveNews($_SESSION["id"], 1); 
         }
   }
}
```

Is it possible?

//Edit:
my full code and how I try to save it...

Comment: You have not defined $db variable..Before using please define $db variable.

Comment: @RajeshPatel in my first Line I included the onnection to the Database with the vairable $db. I don't understand why I get the information that I don't use this...

Comment: Please post all code?so that we can look at it.

Comment: @RajeshPatel okey, I add the full code and the function ^^

Comment: I found my mistake...
I forgot to include in my function the connection and then it works with the variable...